# Rails - Controller DRY - Generic way of doing common filtering/sorting/pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, dry

Developing a new API, I noticed I will be repeating the same code across multiple indexes, trying to avoid this, but not sure on the best method?

Current scenario:

`books_controller`

```
    def index
      books = Book.filtered(query_params).sorted(sorting_params)
      .page(pagination_params[:page])
      .per(pagination_params[:per_page])
      #.includes(:author) // placeholder for dynamic includable associations

      json_response(BooksSerializer.new(books).as_json)
    end
```

Initial Idea I had, was creating `ResourcesService`, that would receive a model, for example `Book` class, and from there apply the methods (filtered, sorted..pagination) and return an ActiveRecord_Relation object to be serialized and returned.

Not sure on how to write it though (as a PORO or Module)

Any tips, on how to make this DRY and reusable across controllers?

Achieving something like, to reproduce on other controllers:

```
books = ResourceService.new(Book, query_params, sorting_params, pagination_params, includables)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `concerns` folder in `app/controllers`, which you can use to store modules which you'll require in many different controllers.

What you're describing is typically what the `concerns` are made for.

Simply create a module inside `app/controllers/concerns` and define your method in it. Then `include` the module (no require needed) in the controller and use it as you want.